# Не срабатывает стиль border: none;

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему у блока c классом .main-app-wrapper__day_current_true не сбрасывается border? И как этого можно добиться?[image: dom element]

Comment: Почитайте про веса селекторов в CSS

Answer (score 1):

‘border:0!important’ ? Если правильно понял вопрос